# Unable to open Jmeter frm cmd prompt

Tags: jmeter

Facing this exception while trying to open Jmeter.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\PerformanceTest\trunk\v2\Jmeter\loadscript\loadscript.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader

```
 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader
line number         : 50
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the author of the script for some unknown reason included [this useless plugin](https://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/) into his test plan.

You need to install the plugin in order to be able to open it in JMeter

I would suggest to remove the plugin from the test plan on next available opportunity and switch to [built-in mechanisms for configuring JMeter and reading properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization), if reading an external .properties file is a must you can pass it to JMeter via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

Comment: it shows the same error message even after placing the tag-jmeter-extn-1.1.jar in JMETER_HOME/lib/ext   folder in jmeter

Comment: you need to restart JMeter to pick up the .jar

Comment: I restarted jmeter and also restarted my computer to confirm.Still shows same error message.Is there any other way to know whether the jar was picked by jmeter or not? TIA.

Comment: You can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to the maximum level and look for `tag` line in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), assuming everything goes fine you should see something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGFSn.png

Comment: This issue is fixed when opening jmeter bat file manually.But When i m trying to run .jmx file through batch file I got the same message.                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
  Batch File : jmeter -Jenvironment="QA" -Jmodule="All Module" -JGlobalThread="1" -JGlobalRampUP="1" -Jencrypted="true" -t loadscript.jmx